# Can javascript be included in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, epoch.js

I am new to web development and I would like to have a feasibility answer:

Basically, I want to develop a `web application`. The application needs to get data from a table of a database and show the data in a `graph`.

For the graph, I found this awesome js solution `epoch.js`: [Click Here](https://fastly.github.io/epoch/)

How can I include this js in JSP application? If no, is there any other good solution?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can include any JS in your JSP files.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP_model_2_architecture

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just add your javascript as you would in a normal HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

JSP is mainly used to create a html page dynamically. So you can easily include or call Java script methods.

Following code give some idea to you.

```
 <%
  String option = request.getParameter("optionMenu");
  if(option.equals("display")){%>
      <script>
           displayMessage();
      </script>
 <%}
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very simple words:

The Servlet (Java) receive the request and use same Java classes to access the information (database, file or other data storage) and prepare the information to send to the client.Then pass the controll (and the data) to JSP that prepare the HTML (presentation layer), including the js too. 
Take in mind that the HTML (with JS ) run on the browser client.
JSP (run on server) can only include the js with html tag SCRIPT.

I hope this help you.